# Why does Dart not figure out the class instance variable in the code below

Tags: dart

I want to understand why Dart can see that the object **b** in `printBye()` function knows it is an *Instance of Bye*, but it does not know how to figure out the instance variable **a**;

```
class Hello {
  void world<T>(T a) {}
}

class Bye {
  int a = 1;
}

class Something extends Hello {
  @override
  void world<T>(T a) {
    printBye(a);
  }
}

void printBye<T>(T b) {
  print(b);    // prints Instance of Bye
  print(b.a); // error
}

void main() {
  new Something()..world(new Bye());
}
```

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/527e6692846bc018f929db7aea1af583

Edit: here's a simplified version of the code that achieves the same effect:

```
class Bye {
  int a = 1;
}

void printBye<T>(T b) {
  print(b);    // prints Instance of Bye
  print(b.a); // error
}

void main() {
  printBye(new Bye());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to look at it: you did call `printBye` with a `Bye`, but you could have called it with any other type. When you call `printBye` with an `int`, that int wont have a `.a`. Therefore, you have to assume that `printBye` could be called with anything. `Object` represents that anything as every class derives from it.

If you are sure that it will be called with a `Bye` or a subclass, you can do this to get rid of the error:

```
class Bye {
  int a = 1;
}

void printBye<T extends Bye>(T b) {
  print(b);    // prints Instance of Bye
  print(b.a);  // not an error anymore
}

void main() {
  printBye(new Bye());
}
```

More info: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#restricting-the-parameterized-type

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for simplifying it.